# Esp32 serial messages to display on lcd

Tags: display, esp32

I'm Pretty new to microcontrollers. I'm running esp32 and adafruit st77xx drivers for my display.
I'm combining this and elmduino library.
I have made a picture wellcome screen and merged it with ELMduino. It works.
Now my question is how do I display like the messages that appear in Serial monitor on my LCD display?

This is my code:

```
    #include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include "ELMduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include "bitmaps.h"
#include "bitmapsLarge.h"

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
#define ELM_PORT   SerialBT
#define DEBUG_PORT Serial

#define TFT_CS        5
#define TFT_RST        4 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
#define TFT_DC         2
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

ELM327 myELM327;


uint32_t rpm = 0;


void setup()
{
   Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));
 tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);
  //Case 2: Multi Colored Images/Icons
  int h = 160,w = 128, row, col, buffidx=0;
  for (row=0; row<h; row++) { // For each scanline...
    for (col=0; col<w; col++) { // For each pixel...
      //To read from Flash Memory, pgm_read_XXX is required.
      //Since image is stored as uint16_t, pgm_read_word is used as it uses 16bit address
      tft.drawPixel(col, row, pgm_read_word(evive_in_hand + buffidx));
      buffidx++;
    } // end pixel
  }
  delay(5000);
  // Use this initializer if using a 1.8" TFT screen:
 // tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);      // Init ST7735S chip, black tab
  tft.setRotation(1); // set display orientation 
  
#if LED_BUILTIN
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
#endif

  DEBUG_PORT.begin(115200);
  //SerialBT.setPin("1234");
  ELM_PORT.begin("ArduHUD", true);
  
  if (!ELM_PORT.connect("OBDII"))
  {
    DEBUG_PORT.println("Couldn't connect to OBD scanner - Phase 1");
    while(1);
  }

  if (!myELM327.begin(ELM_PORT, true, 2000))
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't connect to OBD scanner - Phase 2");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to ELM327");

}


void loop()
{
  
  if (myELM327.nb_rx_state == ELM_SUCCESS)
  {
    rpm = (uint32_t)tempRPM;
    Serial.print("RPM: "); Serial.println(rpm);
      
  }
  else if (myELM327.nb_rx_state != ELM_GETTING_MSG)
    myELM327.printError();
    delay(10);
    }
```

How do I display this message on my LCD display

```
DEBUG_PORT.println("Couldn't connect to OBD scanner - Phase 1");
```

or this one

```
Serial.print("RPM: "); Serial.println(rpm);
```

In the past I've used this commands to display text on my display

```
void loop() {

  tft.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);
  char temp_1[17];
  char usis_1[17];
  char boost_1[17];


   //D-to-string
  dtostrf(temp,3,0,temp_1);
  dtostrf(usis,4,0,usis_1);
  dtostrf(boost,3,2,boost_1);

  
  print_text(20,5,boost_1,5,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(70,50,"BAR",2,ST77XX_GREEN);                 ////Boost

  print_text(5, 90, "Temp engine:",  1, ST77XX_WHITE);
  print_text(70, 90, temp_1, 1, ST77XX_WHITE);            ///Engine_temp

  print_text(5, 100, "Temp usisa:", 1, ST77XX_BLUE);      ///Intake_temp
  print_text(70, 100, usis_1, 1, ST77XX_BLUE);
   
  print_text(146,116,"AM",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  

  delay(1);
  
  
}

void print_text(byte x_pos, byte y_pos, char *text, byte text_size, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(x_pos, y_pos);
  tft.setTextSize(text_size);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}
```

Yesterday I tried writing a simple while loop like

```
int temperature=0;
while (temperature<10){
temperature=temperature+0.1;
}
```

What i got as a result was 0.1 and the display didnt update, it didnt continue like 0.1, 0.2,0.3...

Answer (score 0):

## Why your display did not update:

Your temperature variable is of type integer - this means it can only represent integer values such as -2,-1,0,1,2 from the range of -(2^31) to (2^31) - 1).

Based on your code:

```
int temperature=0;
while (temperature<10){
temperature=temperature+0.1;
}
```

Adding 0.1 to 0 is equivalent to 0, because int types can only represent integers. In other words, it will remain 0 no matter how many times you add 0.1.

## How to simulate a terminal on LCD display

What you need is a buffered display - basically allocate memory to keep the text to display, and discard older lines of text when new input is added.

An example would be something like this:

```
#define LINE_HEIGHT 8
#define NUM_LINES 5

String buffer[NUM_LINES];
int buffer_index = 0; // selects first line to start printing on screen

void print_text(String new_text){
  // add line to buffer
  buffer[buffer_index] = new_text;
  ++buffer_index;

  // clear 
  tft.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);

  // print all text within buffer
  for (int line=0;line<NUM_LINES;++line)
  {
    int current_index = (buffer_index + line) % NUM_LINES;
    tft.setCursor(0, line * LINE_HEIGHT);
    tft.print(buffer[current_index]);
  }
}
```

This is not complete, and there are a couple more things to handle (e.g. dealing with text longer than the width of your screen), but it should give you a good starting point.

Good luck :)